# Filter String of Elapsed Time Average

Tags: c#, devexpress, string-formatting, xtrareport

I am taking an average of elapsed times in a report.

The default filter string to show the times I am taking an average of is {0:T}, which shows up as 00:45:50 which is perfect. But when I take an average of all columns in the group it shows as 00:38:51.99999996. I do not want the decimal points.

I have tried hh:mm:ss, H:MM:SS, HH:mm:ss

Comment: Are you attempting to display this in a .net application?

Comment: Yes, it's in DevExpress' XtraReports Suite.

Comment: How are you printing the summary? Are you using `XRSummary`? It should work with `HH:mm:ss`.

Answer (score 0):

Working Answer:

{0:%h}:{0:%m}:{0:%s}